# Use of the infinitive, always use 'to'?

Tags: infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which is the correct use:

> Thanks for the opportunity of being here?
>   or
>   Thanks for the opportunity to be here?

The idea was to use the verb in infinitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find both to be possible, but "opportunity to be here" sounds more natural to me.

Note that there isn't a general rule: it depends entirely on the particular word that governs it (here, *opportunity*), and there is no logic to which word prefers which construction: they just have to be learnt.